# Not sure how I would go about doing this in WP.. related to custom tags

Tags: customization

Okay, so I want to do something, and after searching on Google I couldn't find any answers. Maybe you guys can help.

basically, I want to assign every post with a little bit of unique identification information. Every post would be tagged white, gray, or black. **I don't want to use categories or tags because I want to display this "unique identifier" on the home page only, and not in the posts where the categories and tags are already shown.**

For example, If I made a post about white tigers, I would want to **identify it as white post** (no racism or anything intended, just an example), and display it on the home page only.

If I made a post about gray tigers, I would want to identify the post as gray, and you get the point.

***How can I go about doing this without a plugin?***

**TL;DR - Want to identify each post with a unique identifier, but can't use categories and tags.**

Please help!

Comment: Take a look at custom taxonomies, they would fit very well.

Comment: Your `and not in the posts where the categories and tags are already shown` is just an issue that can be modified in your theme. Else, Create a custom [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mechanisms in WordPress that would fit your use case: custom taxonomies and post metadata.

Since you have already determined that you want something close to mechanics to categories/tags (which are built-in taxonomies) it seems like custom taxonomy is a right fit for your use case.

See [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) documentation on creating it.